# Show Error icon in Datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show the error text and icon on a datagridview specific cell when this event is fired

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
```

how can i do that?

i tried the following:

```
if (int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()) > nbsstatus)

dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "Max Social Status is " + nbsstatus;
e.cancel=true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Showing column errors in DataGridViews is a bit quirky. In order for the error icon to appear in a cell, you cannot use e.Cancel = true since the icon is only displayed after the cell loses focus, which is prevented when e.Cancel is set for the cell.

In order to work around this, the  RowValidating event must cycle through all cells to determine if an error has been flagged and, if so e.Cancel = true must be set so the user cannot leave the current row until the error(s) have been resolved.

The following VB (I do not have VS for C# for winforms to test with, but you can use one of the free VB to C# converters if you cannot read VB):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellBeginEdit
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = sender
    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText = ""
    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = ""
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = sender
    ' these edits are for illustration purposes only
    Select Case e.ColumnIndex
        Case 0
            If e.FormattedValue = "NO" Then
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText = "No - Column Error Message"
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText
            End If
        Case 1
            If e.FormattedValue = "YES" Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText = "Yes - Column Error Message"
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText
            End If
        Case Else
            e.Cancel = False
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowValidating(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowValidating
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = sender
    For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In dgv.Columns
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(Col.Index).ErrorText) Then
            dgv.CurrentCell = dgv(Col.Index, e.RowIndex) 'set focus
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think this approach works if not cancelling in the Cell Validating causes and exception (where validation was there to prevent that problem). If the cell validating does not do `e.Cancel = true`, the value is still committed in the data source.